# Is there a way to see what is drawn on canvas drawLines _while drawing_ in foreground and is it possible to covert the drawing period to video?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, canvas

I have a custom view that allow me to draw lines on canvas and it works fine .
what I want is to see the drawing while its drawing in the foreground and make the user control the speed of drawing and can it be convert the drawing period to video ?

my code for drawing lines is

```
public   ArrayList<BlockDraw> drawers = new ArrayList<>();
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (BlockDraw blockDraw : drawers) {
            canvas.drawLines(blockDraw.list.pointlist, 0, blockDraw.list.count, blockDraw.paint);
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom view, `onDraw` gets called when the view needs to update, and you draw on the canvas to create the new image. It's just a single image, `drawLines` is just a convenient way of drawing a bunch of stuff.

You can call `invalidate()` at the end of `onDraw` to make it fire next frame, so you're constantly redrawing the canvas - that will let you create an animation by changing what you draw over time, e.g. gradually increasing the end value in `drawLines` from `0` to `blockDraw.list.count` (depending on the "draw speed" you let the user set).

That would just let you draw 1 line, then 2 lines, then 3 etc. If you want to animate each line actually extending from its start point, like you're watching it being drawn by a pen, that's a lot more complex, but you'd do it the same way! Each frame, calculate what needs to be drawn and draw it, depends on how complex you want to make it.

Video is a whole other thing, the emulator will let you record video of your app if that's what you want.